# Detect activity transition to complete before starting a new animation in the new activity on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, listener, transition

I have 2 activities in Android Studio. When I clicked on a button in Activity A, it will transition to Activity B. I have an animation using xml and it would cause an transition animation from A to B.

However after completed transition from A to B, I wanted a new animation to start. For example, I wanted to a Text to appear using alpha animation. When I create the alpha animation, it seems like it is overlapping with the transition animation.

Is there a method to create a listener to wait for the transition animation to complete in Activity B, before the alpha animation starts? I don't want to create a delay in Activity B, as I am looking for a listener method to accurately detect the end of the transition animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [getEnterTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getEnterTransition()) method of `Window` class.

```
class B extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);

       getWindow().getEnterTransition().addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                //start another animation here
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple approach, there is a method in `Activity`,  you can override `android.app.Activity#onEnterAnimationComplete` to do the work after enter animation complete.

```
    @Override
    public void onEnterAnimationComplete() {
        super.onEnterAnimationComplete();
        // do work after enter animation complete
    }
```